# Forcing a newline in the css when calling a stylus user function

Tags: css, newline, stylus

At this moment i'm using this function for passing different browser engines modification (it's outdated I know, but it's used as an example)

```
vendor(prop, args)
    -webkit-{prop} args
    -moz-{prop} args
   {prop} args


vendor('border-radius', '1px 1px 1px 1px')
```

So the output will be:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
```

Only to make it readable, I want to put a new line in the css after this.
So instead of getting this:

```
color:white;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
font-size:2px
```

You'll get this

```
color:white;

-webkit-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

font-size:2px
```

I've tried '\n' but that seems to make it really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control output of blank lines in Stylus (obviously, except `--compress` flag), and, generally, in all other preprocessors too. Postprocessors (like [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) or [Rework](https://github.com/reworkcss/rework)) and tools like [CSSComb](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js) are more suitable for your task.